# Calling 2 functions in an alternating manner in display function

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a function that simply constructs a stick figure in 1 position
I have another function that builds a stick figure in another position.
I now want to call these functions alternatively so that the figure will appear to walk.

I'm not sure if I have to push and pop matrices.

Answer (score 3):

For such rudimentary animation, will a `boolean` flag not do? (OpenGL doesn't even come into it here, it's merely logic)

I.e. in your `draw` method:

```
animate = !animate; // flip flag for 2 possible frames (boolean member variable)
if (animate) {
    // draw position 1
} else {
    // draw position 2
}
```

However, bear in mind this is just some quick sample code to get the idea across - it would result in every frame having the animation occur, which would likely occur so fast to be nauseating. You will have to apply time logic to it as well to make the simple animation not just appear as a blur.

Comment: Might be better to set this up as a frame++ if(frame == max_frame) frame = 0 construct instead, but this does solve his problem as stated.

Comment: Indeed, better still if it is time dependent rather than frame dependent, but for a simple example I thought this would get the message across.

Comment: Thanks guys,I have indeed used flags.
Is there any function equivalent to sleep(),I could use?

Comment: What language is this in? (I was the one who tagged it C++ just on the assumption it was and also to get the syntax colouring for my answer)

Comment: This is in C++ indeed.